# Submit batch job to a server with linux but no slurm?

Tags: linux, matlab, slurm

I used to have access to a slurm server where I would submit the following batch job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=sdmodel
#SBATCH --output=logs/out/%a
#SBATCH --error=logs/err/%a
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --partition=common,scavenger
#SBATCH -c 10
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=12GB
#SBATCH --array=1-236

module load Matlab/R2021a
matlab -nodisplay -r "run('main.m'); exit"
```

Now the new server, is simply linux (no slurm). So the sbatch command does not work. Is there anyway to do something similar?

Comment: They must have some alternative to SLURM running, otherwise everyone is going to be stepping in everyone else’s toes trying to run their big jobs on the same machine at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If the "new server" is the frontend for a cluster you want to use that runs a different batch scheduling system (there are several alternatives to SLURM out there), then you'll need to consult the documentation or sysadmin to identify the new batch scheduling system and then read its documentation.

If the new server is just a single interactive time-shared Linux server (as opposed to a batch-scheduled cluster), then you can probably execute your same script unmodified directly from the command line. One of the benefits of the `#SBATCH` directive format is they are just comments to `bash` and will be ignored when the script is interactively executed by the shell.

If your question is *actually* asking how to run your script in the background and capture the output into files (in a manner similar to execution of your script under SLURM), you could try a command like the following (assuming your script above is named `myscript.sh`):

```bash
$ mkdir -p logs/{out,err}  
$ id=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S` ; echo "Running $id" ; nohup myscript.sh >logs/out/$id 2>logs/err/$id &
```